# update javascript in updatepanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net

lets say I've got a function that iterates over an array. The function is outside the updatepanel, the array is defined within the update panel. The items of the array are dynamically created. On the first try I've realized, that the values of the array do not update when the update panel loads again.

Would be glad if someone can provide a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one: Remove that update panel. Replace it with a proper AJAX call. Update panels will murder your performance and create all manner of maintenance headaches. I am in a world of pain thanks to our dev team using update panels as a way to get AJAX on the quick and dirty.

Comment: I guess this is because of the many asp.net tutorial videos on www.asp.net. It's a good start, but if you want to code clean, it is definitely not the right place. Because I am also new to asp.net, I hope you can provide me some example how to accomplish that in a good manner.

Comment: Sure Johnny - please read some of the great tutorials on the http://encosia.com/ website. Dave Ward does an excellent job of describing AJAX calls and using jQuery templates to produce the HTML on the client with JSON data returned from web services or page methods.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard. I will study this. Is it possible to combine this with the mvp pattern? I guess no. Am I right?

Comment: You can combine it with MVP, but typically you will find MVP on the server, and if you want, MVP again client side in JavaScript.